# Why does my insertion sort afect both of my arrays when only one is being used?

Tags: python, insertion-sort

```
nums = [100,20,30,90]
temp_arr = nums
answer = 0
print(nums, temp_arr)
def insertionSort(arr):
    for i in range(1, len(arr)):
        key = arr[i] 
        j = i-1
        while j >= 0 and key < arr[j] :
                arr[j + 1] = arr[j]
                j -= 1
        arr[j + 1] = key
 
insertionSort(temp_arr)
print(nums, temp_arr)
```

Idk why the array nums is getting sorted when im only trying to sort the temp_arr

Comment: Variables storing non-primitive values (such as lists) actually store references to them. By `temp_arr = nums` you make `temp_arr` and `nums` refer to the same list.

Answer (score 0):

`nums` and `temp_arr` are the same object in memory. When you write `temp_arr = nums`, you are introducing a new name (`temp_arr`) that references that same object as `nums`

Try:

```
nums is temp_arr
```

This should return the result `True`, since `nums` is the same object as `temp_arr`.

To make a new object, you can use:

```
temp_arr = nums.copy()
```

This will actually make a copy of the object and make `temp_arr` reference this new copy. Then try the same test using `is`, this should now return `False`

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is because your assignment

```
temp_arr = nums
```

is done by reference and not by value. So to say it simple any changes to "temp_arr" also affects "nums".

You may find a solution for this here: [List changes unexpectedly after assignment. Why is this and how can I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/list-changes-unexpectedly-after-assignment-why-is-this-and-how-can-i-prevent-it)